# Maurer-Cartan form in Physics

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, gauge-theory, group-theory

I am just reading about the [Maurer-Cartan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurer%E2%80%93Cartan_form) in the context of Lie Groups, although the mathematical definition:
$$\Theta(g)({\bf v}) = (L_{g^{-1}})_{*g}({\bf v})$$
for $g\in G$, $G$ a Lie group, ${\bf v}\in T_g(G)$, seems to be clear for me, I am trying to complement this with some physical intuition. Is there a nice simple application of this 1-form in basic physics, such as in mechanics?

Does it receive another name perhaps within physics in more advanced contexts? I am aware it is related to connections in fiber bundles and connections are related to gauge potentials, but this doesn't seem to provide me with any intuition on the Maurer-Cartan form on its own.

Answer (score 3):

[Maurer-Cartan (MC) equations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Maurer-Cartan+equation) are e.g. used in:

- The [coadjoint orbit method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_method), see e.g. Refs. 1 & 2.
- Various gauge field theories. The [Batalin-Vilkovisky (BV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalin%E2%80%93Vilkovisky_formalism) quantum master equation can be viewed as a generalized MC equation.

References:

1. J.E. Marsden and T.S. Ratiu, *Intro to Mechanics and Symmetry,* 2nd Eds, 1998.
2. B. Kolev, *Lie Groups and mechanics: an intro,* [arXiv:math-ph/0402052](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0402052).

Comment: Thank you for the references, however I am wondering about the form itself, not necessarily the MC equations. I am trying to understand the form in a simple physical case if possible, the second reference just speaks about the isomorphism induced between $TG$ and $G\times\mathfrak{g}$