# Topological meaning of the integral of the trace of Cartan-Maurer forms in Anthony Zee's book on QFT in a nutshell

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, group-theory, topology

I learnt in S. Sternberg's book "Curvature in Mathematics & Physics" over the Maurer-Cartan form that if there is a tangent vector $v \in TG_g$ at a point $g \in G$ ($G$ is supposed to be a Lie-group) there is a unique left-invariant vector field $X$ such that $X(g) =v$. Then the Maurer-Cartan form is the linear map

$$ \omega_a: \quad TG_a \rightarrow \mathfrak{g} $$

that is sending the tangent vector $v$ to the Lie-algebra element $\xi = \omega_a(v) \in \mathfrak{\small{g}}$. Or in other words:

$$\omega(v) = (L_g)^{-1}_\ast v$$

where $L_g$ means left multiplication by $g\in  G$.

This is all pure math, but I always wondered about the possible role of Maurer-Cartan form in physics. On the Physics SE there indeed exists a post which poses exactly this question
[Maurer-Cartan form in Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/497787/) which is very general.

In the meantime I found a concrete example of its use in physics in Anthony Zee's book on "QFT in a Nutshell" (p.225, p.288, p.497)  where he proposes to calculate the integral over $S^3$ or even $S^N$:

$$ Q:= \int_{S^3} \mathrm{tr}\left[ \prod_1^3 g\ dg^\dagger\right]$$

where $\omega = g\ dg^\dagger$ is another representation of the Maurer-Cartan form. He explains further on that the Maurer-Cartan form only needs to be evaluated in the neighbourhood of the identity element of $G$. So if the a group element is represented by $g = \exp(i\theta^a t^a)$ with $t^a \in \mathfrak{g}$ we can write taking into account that $g \approx e$ in the neighbourhood of the identity element:

$$ g\ dg^{\dagger} =-i d\theta^a t^{a} $$

If we then limit ourselves to the well-known group $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and its Lie-algebra we get ($t^a = \sigma^a$, the Pauli-matrices):

$$Q:= \int_{S^3}  \mathrm{tr}\left[ \prod_1^3 g\ dg^\dagger \right]  = i\int_{S^3} \mathrm{tr}\left[\sigma^i\sigma^j\sigma^k\right] d\theta^i d\theta^j d\theta^k = -12  \int_{S^3}  d\theta^1 d\theta^2 d\theta^3  \cong -12 \cdot 2\pi^2 $$

What can I learn from this - apart from the nice mathematical exercise - in particular what is the topological meaning of $Q$? Zee poses this question in the chapter on "Magnetic Monopoles", so I guess, it should be somewhat related with that. I hope that this question is not only of mathematical interest, but also of significance in physics as Lee proposes.

I would really appreciate if I got to know it.

Answer (score 4):

As the three-form given by the trace of $(g^{-1} dg)^3$ is proportional to the Haar volume form on ${\rm SU}(2)$, and there is a tacit pull-back of this to $S^3$,   the quantity $Q/24 \pi^2$ will be the integer winding number (Brouwer degree) of the map $g: S^3 \to {\rm SU}(2)\equiv S^3$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not expect such an abstract concept in the book of A. Lee. I know a pullback only as mapping between differential forms and now I try to understand the "winding number" concept. Could you expand the answer a bit ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Each bit of area on the originating $S^3$ maps to to abit of area on the target $S^3$. If  you count with  orientation as you sweep over the originating $S^3$ you will cover the target $S^3$ an integer number of times. That integer is the winding number.